# Which Map format for performant ArcGIS Visual C# application?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am developing small ArcGIS Visual C# applications.

I can display maps on the interface.

Which map format (.jpg , .tif , .png / ArcGIS supported other map formats ) provides the best performance?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some questions you should ask yourself if you want a good answer. If you are serious about performance you'll want to think of answers to most if not all of these questions!

1. What sorts of images are they, how were they captured or created, and to what purpose are they put?
2. Are the images georeferenced, and must they be displayed along with other georeferenced data, and if so, are they in the same coordinate system?
3. Are the images local, on the network, or on the internet? How many of them will you display at a time?
4. How large are they (dimensions, bit depth, number of bands and file size)?
5. Are they tiled as in an image service with multiple scale levels?
6. Are they/should they be compressed, to what compression ratio, and with what compression scheme? See also this question: [Wavelet vs Discrete compression for imagery](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28066/wavelet-vs-discrete-compression-for-imagery)
7. How are you reading, processing, and displaying them?
8. Is the user allowed to zoom in/out or pan around the image?
9. How do you resample the image so that it can be displayed at non-native resolutions?
10. What are your storage/memory/CPU requirements, target system specifications and required response time?

If you just want a quick suggestion for typical georeferenced true color aerial imagery that resides locally or on the network and is divided into manageable sized tiles (think USGS quarter-quad), and is meant to be displayed on a typical, current desktop PC, use 8-bit, 3-band JPEG-compressed GeoTIFFs at 75% quality. This should provide a good mix of performance, space efficiency, and display quality.

Comment: Veryy thankss for your help... been useful your answer for my I am trying to develop application such as same google earth. I am using .tif map format and I use plenty of zoomin(), zoomout() and pan() processes also I want to high resolution and low distorsion in ZoonIn() process. Which format should I choose for it.

Comment: Again, I couldn't say without more info. Please expand your original question to include as much info as you are able to share. Are you displaying in 2D or 3D? I also see language being a barrier to communication so you might try posting in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gis.stackexchange.com) to see if another user who speaks your language can help translate. See also [Handling questions from non-english writers](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228/handling-questions-from-non-english-writers)